# Conditional observable call with promise

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

i'm trying to do some stuff with observable with no skills :) 
I have something like that (pseudo code):

```
someobservable$.pipe(
  mergeMap(param1 => {
    const condition = await promise;
    return condition ? return EMPTY : return of(param1);
  ),
  mergeMap(param1 => do some stuff)
);
```

So, what i have to do is if condition in first `mergeMap` is true, don't go to second `mergeMap`. This code seems to be working. But how can call and wait for promise in first `mergeMap`? 
Or is it wrong approach at all?

Comment: beware that `await` expects the `mergeMap` callback to be `async`, which isn't. `mergeMap` must return an observable, not a Promise.

Comment: hm, so how can i work around this problem?

Comment: `mergeMap` works with Promises just like with Observables. Anyway you could use `of(param1).pipe(mergeMap(param1 => do some stuff))` before returning it.

Comment: but my promise has nothing to do with `param1`. Anyway i think i figured it out. Just used `return from(promise).pipe(/**/)` in first `mergeMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you go for the full RX way you don't need to use await

```
someobservable$.pipe(
  mergeMap(param1 =>  
        from(promise).pipe(filter(condition=>condition),mapTo(param1))
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you combine before the mergeMap?

```
combineLatest([
  someobservable$,
  from(promise)])
.pipe(
  filter(([_, condition]) => !!condition),
  mergeMap(([param1]) => doSomeStuff))
```

This depends a bit on how someobservable$ behaves. If it only emits once, this will wait for an emission from the `from(promise)` and send the *last* emission from `someobservable$` and `from(promise)`. But it seems it might be what you're looking for, without having any more information about the use-case :)

(Note the es6 array destructuring syntax. `combineLatest`returns an array of emissions.)